# Transition from XIB to Storyboard with data

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xib

So I found a example of how to transition from XIB to storyboard

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"CheckoutStoryboard";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Checkout"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This works great, and then from there if I need to transfer data between storyboard scenes I can use this code to transfer data between segues with this on the first scene.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setMyData:)]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setMyData:)withObject:myObject];
    }
}
```

and this on the second

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myData;
```

However I cannot figure out how to transition from my XIB to my storyboard WITH data. I basically have a ton of variables that are on my XIB that I need on my storyboard, that then get passed around. I know how to do every step except passing data from the XIB to the storyboard. Any ideas?

Comment: XIB is your ViewController ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't provide you any real code but you don't use segues with your above code.
In the example you provided you are creating an instance of the UIViewController you want to display, you are then presenting that view controller modally.

You simply access the variables directly from your desired view controller instance.

`MyCustomUIViewControllerClass * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Checkout"];
vc.myData = <valueHere>
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: Well the reason I instantiate the controller is as far as I have read the only way to go from XIB to storyboard is to do the above. When I attempt your suggested code it erorr's out on me saying that myData is not defined in UIViewController.

Comment: You are to cast it as your ViewController class. Check out the updated answer

Comment: That does make sense, I have changed it however I am still getting the error that my variable is not defined in the context of my custom controller view. Is my definition of the variable correct? @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myData;

Comment: I don't know much Objective-C so I can't help you there but my answer is the correct way of assigning variables to an instantiated view controller before presenting.

Comment: I ended up doing it this way     [vc setValue:<myvalue> forKey:@"myData"];